# flatMap on Map with wildcard type parameter

Tags: generics, scala, types, scala-collections

I'am trying to write something like this:

```
trait Typed[T]

trait Test {

  def testMap: Map[Typed[_], Int]

  def test = testMap.flatMap {case (typed, size) => Seq.fill(size)(typed)}
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
error: no type parameters for method flatMap: (f: ((Typed[_], Int)) => Traversable[B])(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.immutable.Map[com.quarta.service.querybuilder.Typed[_],Int],B,That])That exist so that it can be applied to arguments (((Typed[_], Int)) => Seq[Typed[_0]] forSome { type _0 })
--- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
found   : ((Typed[_], Int)) => Seq[Typed[_0]] forSome { type _0 }
required: ((Typed[_], Int)) => Traversable[?B]
def test = testMap.flatMap {case (typed, size) => Seq.fill(size)(typed)}
```

This code works if change testMap type to:

```
def testMap: Map[Typed[Any], Int]
```

What is the difference and how I can solve my problem?

Comment: Why do you need a wildcard instead of `Any`?  What is your desired use of this trait?

Comment: I show this trait just as example. The problem is I have to write method that takes Map[Typed[_],Int] and transform it to Seq[Typed[_]] according to size variable.

Comment: But `Map[Typed[_],Int]` will have some type. Why not parameterize it, `Map[Typed[A],Int]` instead of wildcarding it?

Comment: Because this map will contains elements with deferent types
(Typed[T1], Typed[T2]...Typed[TN]).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the answer is: You can do it if `Typed` is covariant in `T`, i.e. `trait Typed[+T]`.

### Example

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Typed[+T: Manifest] {
  override def toString = "Typed[" + implicitly[Manifest[T]].toString + "]"
}

trait Test {
  def testMap: Map[Typed[_], Int]

  def foo = testMap flatMap { case (t, s) => Seq.fill(s)(t) }
}

val bar = new Test { 
  def testMap = Map(new Typed[Double]() -> 3, new Typed[Int]() -> 5)
}

// Hit Ctrl-D

scala> bar.foo
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Seq[Typed[Any]]] = List(Typed[Double], Typed[Double], Typed[Double], Typed[Int], Typed[Int], Typed[Int], Typed[Int], Typed[Int])
```

Note that I've made `Typed` a class in this example to get nicer output. You can of course stick with a `trait`.

### Now, why is covariance needed here?

Covariance basically means that if `A <: B` then `X[A] <: X[B]`. So if you were declaring `testMap` as `Map[Typed[Any], Int]` while `Typed` were *invariant*, you were not allowed to pass in e.g. a `Typed[Double]` for a `Typed[Any]` even though `Double <: Any`. Here, the scala compiler seems to be replacing `_` with `Any` in the covariant case (see extempore's comment for an elaboration on this).

*For an explanation of the problem regarding the underscore, I'd refer to Luigi's answer though.*

Comment: +1 great answer. In case anyone's wondering, `T` needs a `Manifest` only to support the `toString`, so you can make this work without it.

Comment: Thanks for reply fotNelton. But unfortunately I can't make Typed type covariant because Typed is actually case class:
case class Typed[+T](fun: T => Any)
in which type T occurs in contravariant position.

Comment: You can work around that like so: `case class Typed[+T, S <: T](fun: S => Any)`, then adapt the rest of the example code to support two type parameters. HTH!

Comment: Re elaboration: SLS 3.2.10, existential simplification rules, rule #4.

Comment: Thanks extempore, that explains it.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is you're trying to pattern match an anonymous function with an existential type parameter.

From the language spec, section 8.5 regarding pattern matching anonymous functions:

> The expected type of such an expression must in part be defined. It
>   must be either `scala.Functionk[S1, ... , Sk, R]` for some `k > 0`, or
>   `scala.PartialFunction[S1, R]`, **where the argument `type(s) S1, ... , Sk`
>   must be fully determined**, but the result type `R` may be
>   undetermined.

`testMap` is an existential type (see language spec 3.2.10). An existential type has the form `T forSome {Q}` where Q is a sequence of type declarations. You have used the special placeholder syntax, so the type `Map[Typed[_], Int]` is equivalent to `Map[Typed[t] forSome { type t }, Int]`, which may make the error message make a bit more sense.

As for a solution, I guess it depends exactly what you're trying to do, which you don't say... :)

Comment: I notice we're not actually pattern matching (no `match`, just a partial function using `case`), so this might not be correct, but perhaps a problem for the same reasons as it doesn't work for pattern matching,

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it an option to parametrize Test?

```
trait Test [A] {
   def testMap: Map [Typed [A], Int]
   def test = testMap.flatMap {case (typed, size) => Seq.fill (size)(typed)}
}
```

Do you have to declare Test before knowing what A will be?