# flatMap on class with parameterized type wont compile

Tags: scala

Can someone tell me why the following:

```
case class Item[A, B, C](a : A, b: B, c: C)
val s1 = Seq(1, 2, 3)
val s2: Seq[Item[_,_,_]] = Seq(Item(3, "q", "r"), Item(4, "s", "t"), Item(5, "u", "v"))
s1.flatMap { i =>
  s2.find(_.a == i) match {
    case Some(i2) => Some(Item(i2.a, i2.c, i2.b))
    case None => None
  }
}
```

Gives me the following compiler errors and the best way to get around it:

```
- no type parameters for method flatMap: (f: Int => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: 
     scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Seq[Int],B,That])That exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Int => Iterable[Item[_0]] forSome { type _0 }) --- 
     because --- argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type; found : Int => Iterable[Item[_0]] forSome { type _0 } required: Int 
     => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?B]
- Cannot construct a collection of type That with elements of type B based on a collection of type Seq[Int].
- Cannot construct a collection of type That with elements of type B based on a collection of type Seq[Int].
```

Comment: There's an interesting question here (I'm not sure why the pattern match lifts the scope of the existential), but this really isn't a corner of Scala you want to get into unless you absolutely have to. It's a good idea to avoid existential types unless you know for a fact that you need them (and even then it's pretty likely you're wrong).

Comment: Oh and apparently making `Item` covariant makes it work. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233115/flatmap-on-map-with-wildcard-type-parameter?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making item covariant does indeed make it compile:

```
case class Item[+A, +B, +C](a : A, b: B, c: C)
...
```

Comment: by the way you don't need a `match`, since you're mapping `None` to `None` you can just use `map`.